# Configure custom port on Azure App Services with containers

Tags: azure, docker

I'm creating an App Service with containers in Azure but in logs I found out that when docker run command is executed, always takes port 80 for starting application, however my application in container is listening on port 5000. How I can change it in order to take port 5000 insted of 80 when it execute *docker run* command?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, you can either use Azure CLI to set:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=5000
```

Or add directly from Azure Portal:

[image]

Hope if helps.